# Viemo API requests limit for videos and thumbnails

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

We are developing a mobile app where user can watch Vimeo videos which are being fetched via the Vimeo API but the problem is that when API request limit reaches above 100 from same IP it starts throwing a 'limit reached' exception.
We are using a Vimeo business account but still we are unable to find any solution or workaround to fix this issue.

Is there any workaround to overcome this problem?
What possible techniques we can use or implement (such as caching)?

Comment: Have you read https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting ?

Answer (score 2):

One of the best solution is to optimize your API responses.
You can use a JSON filter to reduce the size of the responses.

Try to look at the [Vimeo developer API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#json-filter)

Comment: To elabofate, the JSON fields filter parameter grants a higher rate limit (when compared to requests that do not use the parameter). Responses can be quite large, so Vimeo strongly encourages developers use these filters.

Comment: Even still with a lot of users won't it reach way over the limit? Vimeo needs to work that out.